Volume of intersection from multiple cylinders in higher dimensions
You can approximate the "Volume" of a 2D Sphere with a Cylinder (it is exact in 2D, both are circles/disks)
For higher Dimensions, the calculation is just an rougher approximation. 
In three dimensions with just two Cylinders: 
Find the volume common to two circular cylinders, each with radius r, if the axes of the cylinders intersect at right angles. (using disk/washer) 
But i Want N Cylinders in N Dimensions
For an arbitrary Shpere dimension you can use the formula: 
Volume of spheres in higher dimensions?
or
Volumes of n-balls: what is so special about n=5?
Is there a similar easy formula fo the perpendicular intersection of N cylinders in N dimensions?

something like a steinmetz solid but with N cylinders in N dimensions

You can use the same solid-of-rotation integration method to go from $n-1$ dimension to $n$ dimensions for any $n>1$.
